# Identify specific element of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to extract a pattern from a dataset in order to identify specific element in dataframe.
Here's a sample dataset that I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['C', 'D'],['D', 'E'], ['D', 'F'], ['E', 'G'],['F', 'H'], ['Z', 'T'], ['T', 'M'],['V','D']]),
                   columns=['to', 'from'])
```

| to | from |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| C | D |
| D | E |
| D | F |
| E | G |
| F | H |
| Z | T |
| T | M |
| V | D |

The table represents a series of links between elements. The meaning is that A is calculated from B, B is calculated from C, C is calculated from D, D is calculated from E and F, etc.

I'm trying to identify all the input elements given a specific element. Here's my try:

```
obj = 'A'
target = []
flag = True

while len(df[df['to'] == obj])>0: 
    for i in range(0, len(df[df['to'] == obj])):
        for m in range(0, len(df)):
            if obj == df.loc[m,'to']:
                target.append(df.loc[m,'from'])
                obj = df.loc[m,'from']
                print(obj)
                
target = target[-1]               
print(target)
```

With that code, I obtain G as the only input element but i the main problem is that the element D is calculated from 2 elements and i can't manage to obtain G and H as input.

I hope I have been clear and comprehensive and I thank in advance anyone who can help me.

Thank you,

Giammaria

Comment: can you provide an unambiguous expected output?

Comment: scan from the dataframe for possible children and create a linked list from parent to child. Stop scanning for a descendant if the child exists in any of the linked lists. move to the next row.  when scan always ignore the current row.

Comment: @mozway sure. As an example, if i set obj = A, then I expect as output G and H. If i set obj=Z, i expect M.

Comment: hi @GoldenLion thank you for your answer. How can I scan the df in order to identify parent-children relationship? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use a stack  to hold your parent child dependencies using iloc to reposition through the dataframe.  create a sparse list of linked lists and then scan each linked list for a child match, if one is found then move to the next row.  the dependency already exists in the linked list.

Comment: you can use recursion to walk the tree but it will be challenging to code

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is a graph problem.

You want to find the root(s) of the subtree that contains your element.

For this [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) is the ideal tool. You can convert your dataframe to **directed** graph using [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html).

```
import networkx as nx

query = 'A'

# make graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='from', target='to',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph) # important to have directed

# get nodes positions
# 0 = root
degrees = G.in_degree()

# find roots of given element
roots = {node for node in nx.ancestors(G, source=query) if degrees[node]==0}
```

output: `{'G', 'H'}`

The graph:

[image: the directed graph]

###### getting all roots per element

For this you need to split the graph in disjoint subgraphs and to find the root(s) of each graph. Then you can use a dictionary comprehension to build the matches:

```
groups = list(nx.weakly_connected_components(G))
# [{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'V'}, {'M', 'T', 'Z'}]

subgraphs = [G.subgraph(c) for c in groups]

roots = [{node for node,degree in list(g.in_degree()) if degree == 0} 
         for g in subgraphs]
# [{'G', 'H'}, {'M'}]

out = pd.Series({node: nx.ancestors(g, node).intersection(r)
                 for s,g,r in zip(groups, subgraphs, roots) for node in s},
                name='root')

df.merge(out, left_on='to', right_index=True)
```

output:

```
  to from    root
0  A    B  {G, H}
1  B    C  {G, H}
2  C    D  {G, H}
3  D    E  {G, H}
4  D    F  {G, H}
5  E    G     {G}
6  F    H     {H}
7  Z    T     {M}
8  T    M     {M}
9  V    D  {G, H}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph problem.  You can implement your own graph traversal algorithms if you want the exercise, but otherwise it's best to use a standard library for such tasks.

The [`networkx` library](https://networkx.org) is very easy to use and has lots of convenient functions for things like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['C', 'D'],['D', 'E'], ['D', 'F'], ['E', 'G'],['F', 'H'], ['Z', 'T'], ['T', 'M'],['V','D']]),
                   columns=['to', 'from'])

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from(df[['from', 'to']].values)
print(nx.ancestors(g, 'D'))
```

The code above prints:

```
{'F', 'G', 'H', 'E'}
```

Comment: I had started to type an answer a while ago and was interrupted IRL, let me know if you think our answers are too similar and I can delete mine. I think OP rather wanted to find the roots. And +1 btw ;)